# Heap related questions

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory

I know the forum has many questions about heap etc. but nothing helped me this much (except for the understanding of why it doesn't work).

I have a huge quantity of data and of course the heap can't follow. The data I need to store are only integers. Malloc starts returning null quite early.

4 arrays of size: (allocation by malloc)

- 875715
- 875715
- 875715
- 5105043 cells (but it's a 2D array)

Here are my questions:

1) To know the quantity of memory needed, is it:
875715 * 3 * 4 + 5105043 * 4 = 62454492 ? (because integer is 4)
Does it mean around 62 MB? (Sorry if it seems dumb)

2) How can we know the size of the heap available? Is there a way to increase it?

3) I have 3 arrays of the same size, is there an advantage of merging them into one 2D array?
For example, array[875715][3] instead of 3 different arrays (of course, by using malloc)

I use Window seven, 64 bit, 8GB of RAM.

EDIT: Here is a typical allocation I do for the 1D array and for the beginning of the 2D array (first level):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILE_NAME "SCC.txt"
#define ARRAY_SIZE 875714

void getGgraph(int mode,int **graph,int *sizeGraph);
int sizeOfArray(int *array);
void getGraphSize(int mode,int *arr);
void runThroughGraph(int node,int **graph,int *exploredNode,int *magicalPath,int *sizeGraph);
void getMagicalPath(int *magicalPath,int **graph,int *sizeGraph);

    void main()
    {
        int i, *magicalPath,*sizeGraph, **graph;

        /* ------------- creation of the array sizeGraph ------------------ */ // contain the size of each level to initiate the array
        if ((sizeGraph =(int*) malloc((ARRAY_SIZE + 1) * sizeof(sizeGraph[0]))) == NULL) {
            printf("malloc of sizeGraph error\n");
            return;
        }
        memset(sizeGraph, 0, (ARRAY_SIZE + 1) * sizeof(sizeGraph[0]));

        /* ------------- create reverse G graph, this will be a 2D array ------------------ */
        if ((graph =(int**) malloc((ARRAY_SIZE + 1) * sizeof(*graph))) == NULL) {
            printf("malloc of graph error\n");
            return;
        }

        getGgraph(1,graph,sizeGraph);

    // [..... Some more code .....]
    // end of main()
    }


void getGgraph(int mode,int **graph,int *sizeGraph) {
    char int_string[40];
    char stringToAdd[10];
    FILE *integerFile = NULL;
    int i = 0, j = 0, n = 0,stCurrentInt, tail,head,*temp;

    getGraphSize(mode,sizeGraph);

    for (i = 0; i < (ARRAY_SIZE + 1); i++) {
        if ((graph[i] =(int*) malloc((ARRAY_SIZE + 1) * sizeof(graph[i][0]))) == NULL) {
// THIS IS WHERE IT STOPS (i = 594)
            printf("Malloc of graph[%d] error\n",i);
            return;
        }
    }

    if ((temp =(int*) malloc((ARRAY_SIZE + 1) * sizeof(temp[0]))) == NULL) {
        printf("malloc of temp in getGgraph function error\n");
        return;
    }
    memset(temp, 0, (ARRAY_SIZE + 1) * sizeof(temp[0]));

    if ((integerFile = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r")) != NULL) {
        while (fgets(int_string,40, integerFile) != NULL) {
                n = 0, i = 0, stCurrentInt = 0,head = 0; // initialisation

                while (int_string[n] != NULL)   {
                    if (int_string[n] == ' ') {
                        for (j = stCurrentInt; j < n; j++) {
                            stringToAdd[j - stCurrentInt] = int_string[j];
                        }
                        if (stCurrentInt == 0) // first integer is the index
                            tail = (int) atoi(stringToAdd);
                        else {
                            head = atoi(stringToAdd);
                            if (mode == 0) {
                                graph[tail][temp[tail]] = head;
                                temp[tail]++;
                            }
                            else if (mode == 1) {
                                graph[head][temp[head]] = tail;
                                temp[head]++;
                            }
                        }
                        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) { // empty the string for next iteration
                            stringToAdd[j] = NULL;
                        }
                        stCurrentInt = n + 1;
                    }
                    n++;
                }

        }
        free(temp);
        fclose(integerFile);
    }
    else {
        printf("\n File missing in getGgraph.\n");
        return;
    }
}


void getGraphSize(int mode,int *arr) {
    char int_string[40],stringToAdd[10];
    FILE *integerFile = NULL;
    int i = 0, j = 0, n = 0,stCurrentInt,tail,head;

    if ((integerFile = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r")) != NULL) {
        while (fgets(int_string,40, integerFile) != NULL) {
                n = 0, i = 0, stCurrentInt = 0,head = 0; // initialisation
                while (int_string[n] != NULL)   {
                    if (int_string[n] == ' ') {
                        for (j = stCurrentInt; j < n; j++) {
                            stringToAdd[j - stCurrentInt] = int_string[j];
                        }
                        if (stCurrentInt == 0) // first integer is the index
                            tail = (int) atoi(stringToAdd);
                        else
                            head = atoi(stringToAdd);

                        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) { // empty the string for next iteration
                            stringToAdd[j] = NULL;
                        }
                        stCurrentInt = n + 1;
                    }
                    n++;
                }
                if (mode == 0 && head != 0)
                    arr[tail]++;
                else if (mode == 1 && head != 0)
                    arr[head]++;
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("\n File missing in getGraphSize.\n");
        return;
    }
}
```

EDIT2: My program actually works like a charm for smaller inputs.

[..... Some more code .....]: this is after the issue. The failing malloc is inside getGraph, so I don't think the rest is relevant. I free() the arrays later on in the program.

Comment: 1) Are you sure the ints are 32 bit on your 64 bits system? 2) You call malloc with the value `875715`, not `875715 * sizeof(int)`?

Comment: I have edited the post, have a look.

Comment: is there a reason why u use sizeGraph[0] as an argument to sizeof instead of int? that looks like memory leak.

Comment: Ehm, you use `sizeof(sizeGraph[0])` before sizeGraph is initialised? I'm not sure that isn't UB. Best use sizeof(int).

Comment: @lord.didger: No: `sizeof` does not evaluate its operand. This is a perfectly fine pattern, and it eliminates any redundancy.

Comment: @dyesdyes - Your edit means nothing as we do not know those values in the malloc. Besides allocating 62mb is not huge by any stretch of the imagination. My old PC has a 1gb of ram, for example.

Comment: @dyesdyes: Could you please produce a *minimal, complete, self-containing* program that exhibits the problem. I have a feeling that the problem isn't in the code you posted.

Comment: @lord.didger/@MrL: agree with Kerrek; this is standard/best-practice to ensure you get the base-size of the elements of the array that's being allocated - just in case someone changes the declaration from int to long or short, the rest all falls in place.  I would prefer sizeof(*sizeGraph) to mirror the declaration, but that's me just being pedantic.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: fine, the operand is not evaluated. I just wander if sizeGraph has by any chance assigned content and in the if statement assigned new memory space.

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh, OK. In that case, you should complain about the casting to `(int*)`.

Comment: @MrLister: You got to pick your battles...

Comment: Sooo.. this 2D array is "square," you're not allocating 5105043 cells, you're allocating 875714*875714=766,875,009,796 cells.

Comment: No in fact,
it's array[875714][it depends] but overall it's 5105043 as the text file has 5105043 lines.

Comment: And you say it stops at i=594; that's (594-1)*875714 cells = 520,174,116; _*4 = 2,080,696,464 bytes.  You dropped out at about 2Gig.

Comment: Well maybe I misunderstood something but the first level has 875714 cells. For each of those cells, there are different numbers of cell for the 2nd layer.
The i refers to: graph[i]: graph[594]

Can you be more specific ? It's definitely not a square array.

Comment: Look at `getGgraph`, the first for-loop with mallocs in it is allocating out through the 2nd dimension - 875714 cells each, for 875714 rows.  I will have to amend earlier comment - yes you are reading something from the file first - but that's incidental.

Comment: 1) `while (int_string[n] != NULL)   {` You are confusing NULL and '\0' here. 2) `for (j = stCurrentInt; j < n; j++) {` This loop can be replaced by a memcpy() 3) `while (int_string[n] != NULL)   {` This could be a for loop, which would avoid the silly n++ at the end of the loop. 4) `(ARRAY_SIZE+1)` is the only expression where ARRAY_SIZE is ever used. Just increasing ARRAY_SIZE by one would reduce all the (ASIZ +1) expressions to ASIZ. 5) remove the casts, they are not needed and may hide errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. without pulling out a calculator, and without your code, your analysis looks right.
2. The HEAP will grow as needed, constrained only by [OS process limits.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2010/09/27/10068359.aspx).  By default, under windows, you get no more that 2Gig.  Here's a [more specific link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx).
3. no significant advantage.

In your case you'd be better served by adjusting your memory allocation algorithms to allocate what you need and no more.